# VSTS extension task Authentication window

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Trying to authenticate a O365 Logic APP connector through a release which requires user interaction, i can do this in PS session but as VSTS PS tasks has no user interaction iam unable to do this in an agent task!

Would i be able to write and VSTS extension that has a signin popup window, or any way i can do this a standard VSTS task?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t, you may provide the access/refresh token directly.